# How to translate "In conclusion"?

Tags: grammar, writing

I'm practicing writing short articles in Chinese, but I'm not sure how to say "To conclude" or "In conclusion". I can't seem to find an appropriate translation. What is recommended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

总而言之，complete version of 总之，less imperative.
综上所述，in summary (of the previous narration or evidences).
以上，very concise and confident way，but use it carefully，more of a meme these days

Comment: what do you mean by meme? And why would I use 总而言之 over 综上所述, and vice versa?

Comment: @tofu_bacon I guess by meme he means using 以上 to mean "the end". It's a usage commonly seen in Japanese but now becoming popular in Chinese interwebs. 以上.

Answer (score 3):

In academic writing, 综上所述 is often used

Answer (score 2):

On Reddit, there's a [*Writing essays in Chinese--Cheat Sheet*](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/fiky89/chinese_essaywriting_cheat_sheet_a_little_prop_to/) by user [/u/Norcan987](https://www.reddit.com/user/Norcan987/) which might be useful more generally.  It gives quite a few options:

- 最后
- 总的来说
- 总之
- 总而言之
- 最终
- 仔细权衡利弊之后，我认为
- 据这些论点一看，我认为

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

总之 means something like "in sum".

Answer (score 0):

从此可以看出 is a common alternative.

Answer (score 0):

總結來說, (your summary) - In conclusion, (your summary)